# ar drone usability out of the box

Tags: ros, uav

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I want to buy a UAV to play with computer vision applications, and I would like to have a robot that works with ROS more or less out of the box. For instance, I want to know the available nodes allow me easily to read the camera an move the robor without major tweaking?

Thanks,

Juan

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/188014/ar-drone-usability-out-of-the-box/) by [Juan Manuel](https://answers.ros.org/users/4410/juan-manuel/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2014-07-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The ARDrone works out of the box with ROS using the ardrone_autonomy driver. I've been using it for some and haven't had any issues.

The node listens to standard Twist message (/cmd_vel) and it publishes camera information using the ROS standard camera interface.

---

Originally posted by [Gary Servin](https://answers.ros.org/users/10481/gary-servin/) with karma: 962 on 2014-07-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Juan Manuel](https://answers.ros.org/users/4410/juan-manuel/) on 2014-07-29**:
thank you for the answer, I will get an ar_drone then.